# How can I use Haskell to make a bot that automatically fill a web forms?

Tags: haskell, web, bots

For example, I want to write some bot in Haskell, that will automatically test some interactions with websites. I need this bot to fill web forms. Are there ways to do such bot in Haskell?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly it is you're asking. You can do pretty much anything in Haskell. What exactly do you need? Something that can parse html? Something that can perform HTTP requests?

Comment: To @Cubic . From the description of http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider ,  it's just what I need. I need to read pages, fill out forms, and send it to server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at Shpider:

[Hackage page for Shpider](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider)